# Managing build and running of docker containers on one host

Tags: python, docker

I have one server which runs multiple containers

- Nginx
- Portainer
- Several custom HTTP servers
- RabbitMQ

I have a folder structure like this in the home directoty

```
/docker/dockerfiles/nginx/Dockerfile
/docker/dockerfiles/nginx/README
/docker/dockerfiles/nginx/NOTES
/docker/dockerfiles/portainer/Dockerfile
...
/docker/dockerfiles/rabbitmq/Dockerfile

/docker/volumes/nginx/sites/...
/docker/volumes/nginx/logs/...
/docker/volumes/portainer/
...
/docker/volumes/rabbitmq/
```

`/docker/volumes/` contains all the files which the docker containers use, they are mapped into the containers, the containers don't use real Docker volumes and I really want to avoid using them.

I also have 3 Python files:

```
containers_info.py
containers_build.py
containers_run.py
```

`containers_info.py` is basically a dictionary holding rudimentary information about the containers, like the version of the container and the build date, if it should be excluded/included in a build pass, if it should get included/excluded in a run pass

`containers_build.py` imports `containers_info.py` and checks which containers should be built, reads the corresponding Dockerfile from `/docker/dockerfiles/.../Dockerfile` and then builds the container(s) with the Docker Python API, collects some stats and creates summaries, notifies of failures and the like.

`containers_run.py` also imports `containers_info.py` and checks which containers should be run. It contains the information of which volumes to map to, which ports to use, basically all the stuff that would go in a YAML file to describe the container and a bit of management of the currently running container along with it.

It contains multiple snippets like

```
def run_websites(info):
  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  container_name = 'websites'
  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  new_container_name = container_name
  if info['auto-run']: rename_and_stop_container(container_name)
  else: new_container_name = container_name + '-prep'
  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  container = client.containers.run(
    detach=True,
    name=new_container_name,
    hostname='docker-websites',
    image='myscope/websites:{}'.format(versions['websites']),
    command='python -u server.py settings:docker-lean app:websites id:hp-1 port:8080 domain:www.example.com',
    ports={'8080/tcp': ('172.17.0.1', 10001)},
    working_dir='/home/user/python/server/app',
    volumes={
      '/home/user/docker/volumes/websites': {'bind': '/home/user/python/server', 'mode': 'rw'},
    }
  )
  #patch = 'sed -i.bak s/raise\ ImportError/name\ =\ \\"libc.so.6\\"\ #\ raise\ ImportError/g /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/_inotify.py'
  #print container.exec_run(patch, user='root')
  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  if info['auto-run'] and info['auto-delete-old']: remove_container(container_name + '-old')
  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Now I want to move away from this custom solution and use something open source, which will allow me to scale this approach to multiple machines. Currently I can copy the ~/docker/ among servers and execute the modified scripts to obtain the machines I need, but I think that Docker Swarm or Kubernetes is designed to solve these issues. At least somehow that's the impression I have.

My Python solution was born while I was learning Docker, automating it via the Docker Python API helped me a lot with learning Dockerfiles, since I could automate the entire process and mistakes in the Dockerfiles would only mean a little bit of lost time.

Another important benefit of this Python script approach was that I was able to automate the creation of dozens if instances of the webserver on the same machine (assuming that this would make sense to do) and have Nginx adapt perfectly to this change (adding/removing proxies dynamically, reloading configuration).

So, which technology should I start looking into, in order to replace my current system with it? Also, I don't intend to run many machines, initially only two (main+backup), but would, at any point in time, like to be able to add more machines and distribute the load among them, and that by just changing some settings in a configuration file.

Which is the current approach to solve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools you could use in this scenario. If you just plan on using a single machine, `docker-compose` could be the solution you are looking for. It uses a `yaml` style makefile and supports the same build-context (as do standard Docker and kubernetes). It is really easy to get multiple instances of a pod or container running, just using the `--scale` flag eliminates a lot of the headache

If you are planning on running this on multiple machines, I'd say `kubernetes` is probably going to be your best bet. It's really well set up for it. Admittedly, I don't have a lot of experience in `Swarm`, but it's analogous from what I understand. The benefit there is that `kubernetes` can also handle the load-balancing for you, whereas `docker-compose` does not, and you'd have to use some sort of proxy (like Nginx) for that. It's not horrible, but also not the most straightforward if you haven't done something like that before